# Error sending ArrayList via POST on Retrofit Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Tags: android, web-services, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

When I try to send a ArrayList<> using @POST on Retrofit 2 to my webserver, the ArrayList<> is saved on the database, but on Android log I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

I've seen some questions here on SO, but I could not make it work, however I'm a beginner and kinda lost.

This is the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ModelContact> listContact = new ArrayList<>();

    ModelContact c = new ModelContact("5", "OFF", "Test", "12134567", "14646", "email@email.com", "Adress");
    listContact.add(c);
    c = new ModelContact("6", "ON", "Test2", "12123456", "14646", "email@email.com", "Adress");
    listContact.add(c);
```

This is my Retrofit Call

```
Call<List<ModelContact>> callM = contactInterface.createRContact(listContact);
callM.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelContact>>() {
    @Override

public void onResponse(Response<List<ModelContact>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Error: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

And this is my Interface:

```
public interface ContactInterface {

    @GET("recieve")
    Call<List<ModelContact>> getRContact();

    @POST("send")
    Call<List<ModelContact>> createRContact(@Body ArrayList<ModelContact> modelContact);
}
```

Server response when I make a request:

```
[{"id":"13","status":"ON","name":"Test","phone":"123","phone2":"1237855","email":"email@email.com","address":"adsfasd"},{"id":"14","status":"OFF","name":"Test","phone":"123","phone2":"125453","email":"email@email.com","address":"adsfasd"}]
```

ModelContatc class:

```
public class ModelContact {

    String id;
    String status;
    String name;
    String phone;
    String phone2;
    String email;
    String address;

    public ModelContact(String id, String status, String name, String phone,     String phone2, String email, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.phone2 = phone2;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

   public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String nome) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String phone2() {
        return phone2;
    }

    public void setPhone2(String phone2) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Comment: the endpoint is not returning a json

Comment: please post json `response` string from server. it seems your server is sending wrong response. I don't see any error in request to server.

Comment: Posted the response string on the question.

Comment: Seems that parsing failed :) May be because of your ModelContract class, please add it too

Comment: Added the ModelContact class :)

Comment: Hey rafael, i am doing similar thing with retrofit, r u executing any php code in the server "@POST(send)"..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blackbelt said, the server wasn't responding with a json, it's response was from a query on a database which was returning a php error.